# ctags for c99 only

Tags: c, c99, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I've been looking through `ctags` man pages but I haven't found anything that will tell ctags to only record prototypes for `c99 header files`.

Essentially, I have header files for both **C** and **C++** files, but I only want those that correspond to c99 files (ie: no `class` stuff) to be outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctags` has the option `--language` that can force it to interpret files as being of a specific type.

Comment: `--language-force=c` still brings in `class` related elements